# Call to Url from node is not working

Tags: node.js, rest, http, request, postman

I use postman to call to URL with headers etc which is working fine ( I was able to get the token in postman call ) and when I try to use it from node its not working , i Got the following error :

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.122.111.52:445
```

I even **copy the code** from postman and use it in some simple node.js app and its not working , any idea what could be wrong here ?

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Server listen to port :" + port);

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://app.authentication.orc.com/oauth/token',
        headers: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            authorization: 'Basic c2ItY2xvbmUzZjkwNWRmNmRkYzg0YmXCRjlkZmQ0MDdmMCFiMTc0fGNvbm5lY3Rpdml0eSFiMTM3OkpYQUlyd1BrS2tlQVRDWThDNDFsdkhibGNTbz0=',
            accept: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
            token_format: 'opaque&response_type=token'
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);

        console.log(body);
    });
})
```

Comment: Is the post man and node js code are running in same machine?

Comment: @ChandraEskay - Yes from my mac...

Comment: @ChandraEskay - There is option to copy from postman the code if the request you run, I copy it exactly ...this is strange...

Comment: Are you behind any corporate proxy? If yes, then set npm proxy settings.

Comment: @ChandraEskay - yes I guess..I can give it a try please let me know what I should do...

Comment: @ChandraEskay But, if corporate proxy is an issue, his postman wouldn't have fetched results right?

Comment: Basically, `ECONNREFUSED` labelled errors denote that the server which we try to hit is forcefully rejecting our requests, there could be multiple reasons behind this.

Comment: @JennyHilton : `npm config set proxy http://"user:P@ssword"@proxy.server:8080`

Comment: @ChandraEskay - you right please provide is as an answer, now it's working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are behind a corporate proxy then set NPM proxy settings as below.

```
npm config set proxy http://"user:P@ssword"@proxy.server:8080
```