# Why I got ECONNREFUSED again and again on basic http.request()

Tags: node.js

I try this on Node v10.15.3:

```
const http = require('http')

const req = http.get("http://example.com", res => {
    console.log(res.statusCode);
});

req.on('error', e => {
    console.error(`${e.stack}`);
})
```

And get `connect ECONNREFUSED 93.184.216.34:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)`
 all the time.

I can reach this address via Postman so it's not firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code in an external sandbox does work:
https://repl.it/repls/ObviousSpecializedDecagon

It means that it has something to do with your machine.
Try turning off your firewall and test it again, or try a different network.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question properly you would need to provide a little more context. Are you behind a corporate proxy? Are you using a firewall? Which OS are you using?

Just because it works with postman does not necessarily mean that it works with Node.js as well. If you are behind a proxy you need to configure npm accordingly:

```
npm config set proxy http://"username:password"@my.proxy.com:8080
```

This is most likely the solution to your problem, as it is a common issue within company networks. Also, you might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902146/call-to-url-from-node-is-not-working) out.

I hope that helps for now! If not, please provide more information about your setting.